# Can you set a dynamic value to @PreAuthorize in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Right now I use

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('CREATE_USER_PRIVILEGE')")
```

But I want the CREATE_USER_PRIVILEGE to come from a function(). Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
@RestController
class FooController {

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority(@securityService.privilege)")
    @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<String> helloSecurity(@RequestParam("id") Integer id){
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello World");
    }


}

@Service("securityService")
class SecurityService {

    public String getPrivilege(){
        return "CREATE_USER_PRIVILEGE";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks do you know where I can look up the syntax of that parameter? It’s not java code

Comment: Try this: https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.RC1/reference/html/el-access.html

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this great article](https://www.isostech.com/blogs/software-development/spring-preauthorize-spel-examples/)

you have first to autowire your service using constructor or annotation then you can use the Spel language to use it as stated in the following example

```
@RequestMapping(value="/id/{domainObjectId}/dostuff", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json")
@PreAuthorize(value="hasRole('ROLE_DomainObjectAdmin') or @domainObjectServiceImpl.findDomainObject(#domainObjectId).getOwners().contains(#userAccount.getEmployee())")
public String setObjectiveComplete(@PathVariable String domainObjectId, UserAccount userAccount) {
// Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the above solution, I've implemented something like this:

```
@Controller
class TestController {

    //calling a PreAuthorize on method level/ can be used on class level as well
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority(@authorityService.authorities)")
    @RequestMapping("/application")
    public ModelAndView newPage() throws{
        return new ModelAndView(view);
   }
   
}

@Service("authorityService")
class AuthorityService{

    @Value("${app.authorities}") // read roles from properties file
    private String authorities;
    
    public List<String> getAuthorities(){
        // convert the comma separated Strings to list.
        List<String> items = Arrays.asList(authorities.split("\\s*,\\s*")); 
        return items;
    }
    
}
```